# The value attribute is not displaying anything in the input type="checkbox" in React Typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to display some text beside the checkbox in React Typescript and with the value attribute its not working. If i try to set any innerHTML then it throws me an error `input is a void element tag and must neither have children nor use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.`
How should I go about it?

```
interface LetterOptionsProps{
    letterOptions:any

}

export default class LetterOptions extends Component<LetterOptionsProps>{
    render(){
        if(this.props.letterOptions.length>0){
            
        return(
            this.props.letterOptions.map((a:any, i:any) => {
                return (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <input key={i} className="letter-option" type="checkbox" value={a} /> 
                            </React.Fragment>
               
                        );
                    }
                )
        );
        }else{
            return(<div></div>);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to show a label for that checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the input to have a label. As the error points out, inputs are void returns and can't have any children.

Also, FYI, the React key should be placed on the outer-most element being wrapped, i.e. the `React.Fragment` if you still use that, or the `label` as below.

```
this.props.letterOptions.map((a:any, i:any) => (
  <label key={i}>
    {a}
    <input className="letter-option" type="checkbox" /> 
  </label>
))
```

Overall you can also simplify your component code with some applied conditional rendering.

```
export default class LetterOptions extends Component<LetterOptionsProps>{
  render() {
    const { letterOptions } = this.props;
    return letterOptions.length ? letterOptions.map((a:any, i:any) => (
      <label key={i}>
        {a}
        <input className="letter-option" type="checkbox" /> 
      </label>
    )) : null
  }
}
```